# JMeter - cookies no clearing on each new test run

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I'm building a test in Jmeter and have hit a seemingly trivial problem, but I cannot find a way to overcome it.

I need to start a new session each time the test runs (I'm building in the GUI). I thought that setting the HTTP cookie manager in the Thread Group with the 'Clear cookies on each iteration' setting checked would clear the cookies on each new run of the test.

It doesn't seem to work however - when running a test for the second time the user session initiated in the previous run is still there.

In fact I am now getting a 494 server error (Cookie too large) because the cookies are accruing in size with each run of the test.

Any ideas on how to clear the cookies with each new run of the test?

Comment: how did you add cookies ?

Comment: they're being added by the application (Magento)

Comment: can you show in vuew results tree the cookie content ?

Comment: hey @UBIKLOADPACK - thanks for this - it was related the environment I was working on and I sorted it

Comment: no pb, in this case I would suggest your delete your question :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, issue was related to environment and not JMeter.

Most probably Cookies we stacking up due to some infinite redirection or similar environment problem.

If you face any issue with Cookie Manager, refer to [reference documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is a JMeter problem, most likely you're receiving an incorrect cookie via [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header from the system under test.

You can troubleshoot this issue by [enabling extra logging for JMeter's HTTP Cookie manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), this can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
 <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the changes

---

Also be aware that you can manually remove all stored cookies in an arbitrary place of your script

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.getCookieManager().clear()
   ```

Comment: This did not work for me. Use sampler.getCookieManager().getCookies().clear() instead